# Stack DIVs in one line if there is enough room

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to create a horizontal timeline and avoid one extremely performance price issue.

suppose we have 3 events represented as 3 divs.

```
<div class="timeline">
<div id="Ev1">
  Event 1
</div>
<div id="Ev2">
  Event 2
</div>
<div id="Ev3">
  Event 3
</div>
```

now I want them to display each in its required time according to the horizontal axis i have tried to use `margin` for that but sure did not work because they are not set to `float:left;`
the issue is i don't want them to float left i want to control which event is displayed where on the horizontal axis either by using `margin` or `left:##px` or any other means that can be converted to a time calculation.

so here is the CSS:

```
body {
  background: #AAA;
}

.timeline {}

.timeline div {
  height: 30px;
}

#Ev1 {
  background: #e10b1f;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 231px
}

#Ev2 {
  background: #fb7d29;
  width: 230px;
}

#Ev3 {
  background: #96cf67;
  width: 460px;
}
```

I know i could use JS to calculate how many events i have in parallel and fix the `top` property according to the `offset` and so on but this is exactly what i am trying to avoid because it causes a sever performance hit when we are looking at hundreds of events on the timeline.

I am looking for an elegant way to tell the browser that if there is enough room on a single line display the DIVs one after the other but if not then stack them one on top with there respective offset according to the event time.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/arthurv/pen/WwbmRr

Comment: Not possible without JS. Not even flexbox can calculate the widths and then determine layout. It doesn't do *"if" statements*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got what you are trying to do.
Does this work?

```
.timeline div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: no.. this way they are just displayed one after the other with no ability to control their horizontal position..

Comment: you can edit and see the result in the code-pen link i provided

Comment: Oh I see.. Will answer if I think of anything.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. The CSS architecture

Use percentage based widths + floats for your indidivual events :

```css
body {
    background : #AAA;
}

.timeline {
    width : 100%;
}

.timeline div {
    float : left;
    height : 30px;
}

#Ev1 {
    background : #e10b1f;
    width : 41.51%;
}

#Ev2 {
    background : #fb7d29;
    width : 17.82%;
    margin-left : 5%;
}

#Ev3 {
    background : #96cf67;
    width : 27.66%;
    margin-left : 8%;
}

#Ev4 {
    background : #ffc901;
    width : 17.82%;
}

#Ev5 {
    background : #88aaff;
    width : 67%;
    margin-left : 12%;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
    <div id="Ev1">
        Event 1
    </div>
    <div id="Ev2">
        Event 2
    </div>
    <div id="Ev3">
        Event 3
    </div>
    <div id="Ev4">
        Event 4
    </div>
    <div id="Ev5">
        Event 5
    </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. Generating the values for your widths

To dynamically calculate the actual percentages for the widths of `#Ev1`, `#Ev2`, `#Ev3`, you could use eg. [**PHP**](http://php.net/), [**Less**](http://lesscss.org/) or [**Sass**](http://sass-lang.com/).

For example, if you'd use Sass, you could using this code to generate the CSS shown in #1 :

```
$events : (
    1 : (0, 41.51%, #fb7d29),
    2 : (5%, 17.82%, #fb7d29),
    3 : (8%, 27.66%, #96cf67),
    4 : (0, 17.82%, #ffc901),
    5 : (12%, 67%, #88aaff)
);

@mixin generate-events() {
    @each $key, $value in $events {
        #Ev#{$key} {
            background : nth($value, 3);
            width : nth($value, 2);
            $margin-left :  nth($value, 1);
            @if $margin-left != 0 {
                margin-left : $margin-left;
            }
        }
    }
}

body {
    background : #AAA;
}

.timeline {
    width : 100%;
}

.timeline div {
    float : left;
    height : 30px;
}

@include generate-events();
```

Comment: that's not helping because i cannot control the exact horizontal position of each event on the timeline they all just stick to each other..

Comment: @Mortalus : You can control the distance between two events using  `margin-left`. Check out my updated answer for an example.